# Using redux-saga with setInterval - how and when to yield

Tags: generator, redux-saga

Having just moved from thunks to sagas I'm trying to find the best way to call `setTimeout` and then from within that function call another function (in this case `corewar.step()`). This was my original code which works as I'd expect.

```
  runner = window.setInterval(() => {

    for(let i = 0; i < processRate; i++) {
      corewar.step()
    }

    operations += processRate;

  }, 1000/60)
```

This code is inside a `saga` and I believe that I should be able to wrap function calls within `call` as I've done in other areas in the application.

I've tried wrapping the `setInterval` call in a `call` and leaving everything else as it is, which results in `step()` never being called.

```
  runner = yield call(window.setInterval, () => {

    for(let i = 0; i < processRate; i++) {
      corewar.step()
    }

    operations += processRate;

  }, 1000/60)
```

I've tried, leaving the `setInterval` as it is and wrapping the `step()` function in a call and changing the anonymous function signature to `function*` which also results in `step()` never being called.

```
  runner = window.setInterval(function*() {

    for(let i = 0; i < processRate; i++) {
      yield call([corewar, corewar.step])
    }

    operations += processRate;

  }, 1000/60)
```

Finally, I've tried wrapping both, which again results in `step()` never being called.

```
  runner = yield call(window.setInterval, function*() {

    for(let i = 0; i < processRate; i++) {
      yield call([corewar, corewar.step])
    }

    operations += processRate;

  }, 1000/60)
```

It feels like I'm missing something here so my question is, should I need to wrap these functions up in `call` at all or is this wrong?

The follow on question if I am supposed to wrap the outer `setInterval` in a `call` would be how should I be defining a function as a parameter to `call` which also wants to yield either a `put` or `call` itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
const anotherSaga = function * () {
  const runner = yield call(setInterval, () => {
    console.log('yes');
  }, 1000);
  console.log(runner);
}
```

This works pretty fine for me. In your second snippet there is a double `)` at the end where should be only one.

Comment: Hmm, you're right I must have had some odd combination of trying to use generators as CB params (the extra bracket was just a typo, removed from q)

Comment: The real problem is that you cannot call a generator inside this function it will never be executed. What can you do to change the state every 1 sec?

Answer (score 17):

There is a section in the saga-redux docs called "[Using the eventChannel factory to connect to external events](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events)", that suggests using `channels`.

This section is also providing an example for a `setInterval` implementation:

```
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga'

function countdown(secs) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
      const iv = setInterval(() => {
        secs -= 1
        if (secs > 0) {
          emitter(secs)
        } else {
          // this causes the channel to close
          emitter(END)
        }
      }, 1000);
      // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
      return () => {
        clearInterval(iv)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

You would then use `yield call` and `yield takeEvery` to set it up:

```
const channel = yield call(countdown, 10);
yield takeEvery(channel, function* (secs) {
    // Do your magic..
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party here but this is the top search result for the question of setting a timer in a saga. There's an alternate solution due to the nature of sagas. [From here.](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1610#issuecomment-423390452)

I adapted this so:

```
function* callSelfOnTimer({ value }) {
  // Do your work here
  ...
  // If still true call yourself in 2 seconds
  if (value) {
    yield delay(2000);
    yield call(callSelfOnTimer, { value });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you also need to add this:

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

function* callSelfOnTimer({ value }) {  
    // Do your work here  
    ...  
    // If still true call yourself in 2 seconds  
    if (value) {  
        yield delay(2000);  
        yield call(callSelfOnTimer, { value });  
    }  
}
```