# Redux saga: how to call an action creator inside setInterval()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I'm using `Redux saga` in my React Native app and have a generator function that looks like this:

```
function* func1(action) {
  setInterval(() => {
    yield put(ActionCreators.actionCreator1(action));
  }, 1000)
}
```

where `ActionCreators` is a set of action creators defined elsewhere. This doesn't work, because I'm trying to call the action creator inside the callback of `setInterval`, which isn't a function generator.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044439/using-redux-saga-with-setinterval-how-and-when-to-yield

Comment: That does, thanks! I posted another related question here if you have any insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517167/redux-saga-how-to-cancel-one-task-from-another-that-didnt-initiate-it