# Redux saga: how to cancel one task from another that didn't initiate it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

I'm reading [this article](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html) on cancelling tasks in `Redux saga`. Basically the example they have goes like this:

```
function* main() {
  yield call(task1);
  yield cancel(task1);
}

function* task1() {
  <...>
}
```

Here `main` can cancel `task1` because it called it. In my code I'm running the functions like this:

```
function* task1() {
  <...>
}

function* task2() {
  yield cancel(task1);
}

function* main() {
  takeLatest(actionCreator1, task1);
  takeLatest(actionCreator2, task2);
}
```

Cancelling `task1` in `task2` doesn't work, presumably because `task2` didn't invoke `task1`. Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is probably to have main do it's own implementation of something similar to takeLatest, but with extra logic to cancel the other task.

If you only want action2 to do the extra cancel, then it will look something like this:

```
function* main() {
  let firstTask;
  let secondTask;
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take([actionCreator1, actionCreator2]);
    if (firstTask) {
      // Always cancel task 1, whether we got action 1 or action 2
      yield cancel(firstTask);
    }
    if (action.type === "the type of action 1") {
      firstTask = yield fork(task1, action);
    } else {
      if (secondTask) {
        // Only cancel task 2 if we got action 2
        yield cancel(secondTask);
      }
      secondTask = yield fork(task2, action);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want both actions to cancel both tasks, it's a bit simpler:

```
function* main() {
  let task;
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take([actionCreator1, actionCreator2]);
    if (task) {
      yield cancel(task);
    }
    if (action.type === "the type of action 1") {
      task = yield fork(task1, action);
    } else {
      task = yield fork(task2, action);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found a simpler (but less elegant) way to do it with local variables, but going through your code here, your logic is sound and this is a really good solution. I appreciate it!